# Difference between /fp:strict and /fp:precise?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point, floating-point-precision, visual-studio-2010

When do you use fp:strict as opposed to fp:precise? Is it better to use the former if I want "more precise" calculations and avoid rounding errors? What is the heuristic behind using either?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The standard IEEE 754 specifies a method for floating point calculations and storage of floating point values in memory.

Using `fp:strict` means that all the rules of IEEE 754 are respected. `fp:strict` is used to sustain bitwise compatibility between different compilers and platforms.

`fp:precise` weakens some of the rules, however it warranties that the precision of the calculations will not be lost.

`fp:fast` allows compiler specific optimizations and transformations of expressions containing floating point calculation. It is the fastest methods but the results will differ between different compilers and platforms.

Comment: Do you know where I can learn about the rules that the :precise relaxes?

Comment: @unj2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=msvc-170